# How do I use Yarn version 3.5 on Github Actions? ("Error: cannot find module ... /yarn-3.5.0.cjs")

Tags: continuous-integration, github-actions, yarnpkg, yarn-v3

On our local machines, we've installed the latest version of Yarn for our node version of `16.17` per the [instructions on the Yarn website](https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/install):

`corepack enable`

`corepack prepare yarn@stable --activate`

We found this step was necessary to make it work locally as well:

`corepack prepare yarn@<version> --activate`

We use Github actions to do things like lint and test our code. Here's the *lint.yml* file:

```
name: Lint

on:
  # Trigger the workflow on push or pull request,
  # but only for the main branch
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  run-linters:
    name: Run linters
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Check out Git repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Use Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: "16.17"

      - name: Install Node.js dependencies
        run: yarn install --immutable --immutable-cache --check-cache

      - name: Run eslint
        run: yarn eslint src/ --max-warnings=0

      - name: Run Prettier
        run: yarn prettier src/ --check
```

According to the Github Actions docs, [yarn should be installed](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/automating-builds-and-tests/building-and-testing-nodejs#example-using-yarn) in this CI environment:

> GitHub-hosted runners have npm and Yarn dependency managers installed. You can use npm and Yarn to install dependencies in your workflow before building and testing your code.

However I believe the Yarn version Github actions uses is 1.something, as it seems to be the one installed when `yarn` is installed with `npm install -g yarn`, the old method of installing Yarn.

As such, we get the following error when Github actions tries to use `yarn`:

*output from github CI*

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:959
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/home/runner/work/ui/ui/.yarn/releases/yarn-3.5.0.cjs'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:956:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:804:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
```

I've tried various methods recommended online for telling Github which version of node and yarn to use. For example, I've added `packageManager` property to our `package.json`:

*package.json*

```
...
  "packageManager": "yarn@3.5.0",
...
```

That didn't work, so I added `engines` property to `package.json`:

*package.json*

```
...
"engines": {
    "yarn": ">=3.5.0"
}
```

The error remained the same, so I tried directly installing and activating the latest version of yarn in the github actions `.yml` file:

*lint.yml*

```
name: Lint

on:
  # Trigger the workflow on push or pull request,
  # but only for the main branch
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  run-linters:
    name: Run linters
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Check out Git repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Use Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: "16.17"

      - name: Install latest Yarn
        run: corepack prepare yarn@stable --activate

      - name: Activate latest Yarn
        run: yarn set version stable

      - name: Install Node.js dependencies
        run: yarn install --immutable --immutable-cache --check-cache

      - name: Run eslint
        run: yarn eslint src/ --max-warnings=0

      - name: Run Prettier
        run: yarn prettier src/ --check
```

I can't be entirely certain this error is because of a failure to use yarn v3.x, but that's my suspicion as this whole setup worked with our `yarn.lock` was in the yarn v1.x format and we all used yarn v1.x locally. It's only with the upgrade that it fails to work on github actions.

**How can I instruct Github Actions' runner to find / use the latest version of Yarn?**

*Additional Info*:

*.yarnrc.yml*

```
nodeLinker: node-modules

yarnPath: .yarn/releases/yarn-3.5.0.cjs
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me that you've gitignored too much. This is the recommended setup from Yarn docs:

https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/qa#which-files-should-be-gitignored

I was facing similar problems when I was ignoring `.yarn/` instead of `.yarn/*` with the ignores to that rule followed after as recommended in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

this was help me (NOT SURE THAT THIS IS CORRECT WAY)

yarn by default added in gitignore .yarn (full folder),

but i decided to add **only** **.yarn/cache** folder in **.gitignore**, not full .yarn.

now my ci is working.

[gitignore in root of monorepo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgYjv.png)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `.yarnrc.yml` file that has a `yarnPath`

e.g.

```
nodeLinker: node-modules
yarnPath: .yarn/releases/yarn-3.6.0.cjs
```

Make sure the file exists, in this case `.yarn/releases/yarn-3.6.0.cjs`

You can generate by `yarn set version 3.6.0`, just replace with the equivalent version your file expects

Answer (score 1):

The key is to enable corepack prior to setup-node:

```yaml
...

steps:
  - uses: actions/checkout@v4
  - name: Enable Corepack
    run: corepack enable
  - name: Use Node.js 20.x
    uses: actions/setup-node@v4
    with:
      node-version: '20.x'
      cache: 'yarn'

...
```

This also helped me: https://github.com/actions/setup-node/issues/480

Comment: Thank you, this was the issue for me - corepack allows the package to determine which version of `yarn` gets used, rather than just the global default.

Answer (score 0):

try

`packages.json`

```json
{
  ...
  "packageManager": "yarn@4.0.2"
}
```

`workflows.yml`

```yaml
   steps:
      - name: enable corepack
        run: corepack enable

      - name: set node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v4
        with:
          node-version: 'lts/*'
          cache: 'yarn'
```

```bash
Run actions/setup-node@v4
  with:
    node-version: lts/*
    cache: yarn
    always-auth: false
    check-latest: false
    token: ***
  
Attempt to resolve LTS alias from manifest...
Found in cache @ /opt/hostedtoolcache/node/20.11.1/x64
Environment details
/usr/local/bin/yarn --version
4.0.2
```