Is it possible to update a version in a preinstalled ubuntu-latest image in GitHub Actions?
The ubuntu-latest runner in GitHub Actions by default has Yarn v1 according to their docs. I would like to override that to Yarn 4. Is this even possible? If yes, is there a path I should look up to update this?

This is a very broad question as posed. For Yarn specifically, if you just enable corepack it should pick up and use the correct package manager: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77902268/3001761

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

I'd suggest you use a custom container where you can control the versions you want to use when running the pipeline. Here's an Ubuntu Dockerfile I wrote up:
FROM ubuntu:latest
ARG NODE_MAJOR_VERSION=20
RUN echo "deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/nodesource.gpg] https://deb.nodesource.com/node_$NODE_MAJOR_VERSION.x nodistro main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list

RUN apt update && apt install ca-certificates curl gnupg nodejs npm -y

WORKDIR /usr/app
COPY ./ /usr/app
RUN npm install -g corepack
RUN corepack enable && \
    yarn init -2 && \
    yarn set version stable && \
    yarn install


RUN echo $(yarn -v)

You can use this by building the Dockerfile, putting it in some registry and then using the container option in the pipeline. I recommend editing to taste, since I don't know your project setup. This is all mocked from here.
    container:
      image: docker://ghcr.io/<OWN-REG-HERE>/<OWN-IMG>:<TAG>
      credentials:
        username: ${{ github.actor }}
        password: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

Alternatively, you may attempt to bump the version in the pipeline itself. That should be possible, but I'd recommend having dependencies in an image so that you have the latest working copy
